# jqgrid refresh false after selecting row in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm refreshing the jqgrid Using setInterval(inside jqGrid-LoadComplete event). If I select any  row in the grid how can I stop refreshing the jqgrid. Because it's unchecking my selected row.

```
var timer; //Global Variable 
function populateGrid() { /*Grid population Code URL:url, <ColNames> <colModel> **********/
    loadComplete: function () {
        var myGrid = $("#<grid_name>");
        $("#cb_" + myGrid[0].id).hide();
        var resCount = $("#<grid_name>").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'reccount');
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            $("#<grid_name>").trigger("reloadGrid");
        }, 4000);
    },
    onSelectRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global variable for timer

```
var timer;
```

In your jqGrid load event, call the function with refresh code

```
timer = setInterval(fn, intTimeoutInMilliseconds);
```

In code for select row event

```
onSelectRow: function(id){
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But ClearTimeout is not solving the issue. It's unchecking my checked check box and one more thing I observerd that "Loading..." lable is keep on blinking at center of the grid. I have given setInterval time duration as 10000

Comment: the label keeps on showing because your setTimeout function is repeatedly calling by itself. Can you show some of your code where you are calling the setTimeout function?

Comment: var timer;//Global Variable

Function populateGrid()
{
/*Grid population Code 
URL:url,
<ColNames>
<colModel>
**********/

loadComplete: function() 
 {
 var myGrid = $("#<grid_name>");
 $("#cb_"+myGrid[0].id).hide();
 var resCount=$("#<grid_name>").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'reccount');

 timer = setInterval(function(){ $("#<grid_name>").trigger("reloadGrid"); },4000);
        },
 onSelectRow:function (rowid,status,e)
 {
 clearTimeout(timer);
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to stop refresh if you select a row. You can do that by checking whether a row is selected inside the setInterval. "grid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow')===null"

Code:

```
var timer; //Global Variable 
function populateGrid() { /*Grid population Code URL:url, <ColNames> <colModel> **********/
    loadComplete: function () {
        var myGrid = $("#<grid_name>");
        $("#cb_" + myGrid[0].id).hide();
        var resCount = $("#<grid_name>").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'reccount');
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            if($("#<grid_name>").jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow')===null){
                   $("#<grid_name>").trigger("reloadGrid");
            }
        }, 4000);
    },
    onSelectRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Srinivas. It works perfectly fine, but if I'm not selecting any row still the "Loading..." text at center of the grid is keep on blinking. If I increase the interval time to 10K also facing the same issue. Please provide your comments

Comment: I am little confused now. If you don't want the Loading text then you can add the configuration --loadui: 'disable'-- in your grid. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: thanks for the response. I added the loadui:'disable' it's stopped refreshing the grid. Issue because of the SetInterval(10000) "Loading..." is keep on blinking at the center of the grid.I want to see "Loading..." text whenever it's going to refresh on every 10000ms. Here attaching the grid configuration

 loadtext: 'Retrieving Data...'. 
 loadui: 'disable',
 multiselect: true,
    sortname: '<col_name>',
 viewrecords: true,
 multiboxonly: true,
 sortorder: "desc"

Comment: Srinivas one more thing just observerd that If I left the browser for some time like 5/7 mins jqGrid keep on refreshing and not able to select the row in grid.

Comment: I want to clear on the answer: `loadui:'diable` - This will not show the loading message,but It will not refrain from reloadGrid.